# How to make two column inside mat-card using Angular8

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to put all my input fields inside the mat-card in column wise using Angular8. I am explaining my code below.

```js
    <mat-card>
       <form [formGroup]="storeForm" novalidate>
          <div formGroupName="ShippingRule">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="margin-left: 85%;" (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
             <section class="container border mb-4 p-3" *ngFor="let address of addresses; let i = index;">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-6">
                      <h4>Address {{i + 1}}</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-6 text-right">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove</button>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Address</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="address.address" name="address_{{address.id}}" placeholder="St. Thomas Apartment"/>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Street</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="address.street" name="street_{{address.id}}" placeholder="South Street"/>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>City</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="address.city" name="city_{{address.id}}" placeholder="Mumbai"/>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Country</label>
                         <select class="form-control" formControlName="address.country" name="country_{{address.id}}" placeholder="India">
                            <option value="india">India</option>
                            <option value="usa">USA</option>
                            <option value="england">England</option>
                         </select>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </section>
          </div>
       </form>
    </mat-card>
```

Here I need to equally divide all input into 2 columns . As per my code its coming in line by line.

Comment: Also as a side note, when using 'row' you only need to include this as the child of the container. i see here you're putting one in after each 'row' which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you're trying to use the bootstrap layout classes 
`row`, `col-6` etc.

Have you included bootstrap in your project?

Comment: Yes..I have included.

Comment: Can you confirm that these classes work independently of the material form?

Comment: If material has such kind of facility then I can ignore bootstrap.

Comment: In that case you may want to look into the `Grid List` api which should help with formatting. https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I ran your code and saw that it does split evenly into two columns. Or isn't that what you mean?

Did you enter the bootstrap scripts in the head tag?

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```